# unable to create object to sealed class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm having a sealed class with interface.

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class OrderProcessor : IDisposable
{.....}
```

this is separate class having interface implementation.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IDisposable
{
    void Dispose();
}
```

i want to create object in another class.

```
OrderProcessor processor = new OrderProcessor();
```

at the time of create object it gives an error.

Error:

```
The type initializer for 'OrderProcessor' threw an exception.
```

Inner Exception:

```
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: assemblyString
```

Note : assemblystring is no where present in my project.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: Include constructor and error message in your question.

Comment: just now i edited my code with error description.

Comment: We still need to see the constructor for OrderProcessor

Comment: i'm not passing any constructor to OrderProcessor. @GBleaney

Comment: The constructor isn't something thats passed in, its the method that gets called when you call `new OrderProcessor ();` It would look something like `public OrderProcessor(){ ... }`

Comment: my wordings were wrong but intended to say that i dint use any constructor in Orderprocessor. but i used some constants and static readonly classes.

Comment: If there is no constructor, its possible that some of the static members of that class could be throwing the exception if the `new OrderProcessor` is the first time you referenced the class. Its also possible this this is an issue in appSettings as per this question: http://forums.asp.net/t/1294398.aspx

Comment: @RanjithNagiri You are using the parameterless constructor. This constructor does something that eventually comes up with the given exception. Notice the keyword **inner exception**.

Comment: Before we move on guessing the StackTrace would help.

Answer (score 0):

Is not there done any reflection inside of the type? Or maybe in related framework? If the class does some reflection magic and it needs another assembly then make sure it is available on expected path.

`assemblyString` in the error probably refers to name of the parameter in the constructor and there is not passed any value

See `Assembly.Load` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ky3942xh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or
See `InternalST.LoadAssemblyFromString` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.internalst.loadassemblyfromstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please provide full stack trace for further information.